# Creating component from array and avoiding duplicate

Tags: reactjs

I am using an API to fetch some data and i am creating a new *Link* element for each component of the array based on individual keys. The array has a property *category* which i am actually rendering to the DOM. Some categories repeat themselves multiple times, so i would like to only render each of them once and skip the other iterations. Can that be done with the *map* method or do i have to create a separate function?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Catalog() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");

    const products = await data.json();

    setProducts(products);
    console.log(products);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <p key={product.id}>
              <Link to={`/catalog/${product.id}`}>{product.category}</Link>
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: are the categories sorted ? if so, you can create a currentCategory variable and check if it's the same as the previous category and skip/return accordingly...

Comment: You may try [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before you `map`.